# pfsense, in bind, zone is not working

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, internal-dns

I have installed and configured Bind on latest pfsense, did setting and configured the zones. i have setup the local resolved to the bind server ip like 10.0.0.50. bind is running, but still when i query the zone domain, i see no records, even though i have configured the zone properly. I want to setup Internal DNS in a VPC. I have disabled the local dns resolver as well, but still cannot get the zone working

[image]

Here is configuration file

[image]

Comment: The `Disable This Zone` box appears to be checked...

Comment: sorry, actually it didnt worked even after enabling the zone.

Comment: would be nice to see what the actual `named.conf` looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems missing the view,
try to add a view ( tab view ) 
and add to zone. ( tab zone, field view )